# Probability theory in card

Tags: probability-theory, education

I trying to solve it exercise using excel, but it's too hard
We have a deck of 11 cards.
There are 2 black cards in the deck, 112 white and green cards more than yellow ones.
A = 11
B = 122
C = X2
D = Y.
You draw two random cards from the deck and have a 27% chance of drawing cards with the same color.
How many green cards?
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  The phrasing is a bit vague....are we to assume that we have $3$ variables, $W,G, Y$ such that $W+G+Y=78$ and $W+G=18+Y$?  Something else?  In any case, the natural first step is to express the goal in terms of those variables.

Comment: Is "white and green card" a kind of card?

Comment: @peterwhy yes, its kind a card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let a deck with $22$ black cards, $18$ white cards, $x$ green cards and $60-x$ yellow ones. Your condition is $x>60-x$, i.e. $x>30$.

The probability of $A:$ "draw two cards with the same color" is,
$$\mathbf{P}(A)=\frac{22}{100}\frac{21}{99}+\frac{18}{100}\frac{17}{99}+\frac{x}{100}\frac{x-1}{99}+\frac{60-x}{100}\frac{59-x}{99}=\frac{2x^2-120x+4308}{9900}=\frac{27}{100}$$
The parabola is solved with $2x^2-120x+1635=0$, i.e. $x=39.083$ or $x=20.91$ (they are not integers). If your assume $x=39$, the exactly probability is:
$$\mathbf{P}(A)=\frac{22}{100}\frac{21}{99}+\frac{18}{100}\frac{17}{99}+\frac{39}{100}\frac{38}{99}+\frac{21}{100}\frac{20}{99}=0.2718$$

With exactly $27\%$ there is no solution. But with $27.18\%$, the solution is $39$ green cards.